# So this the first app I've developed in Nativescript and I'm lost on how to assign a profile or cert to a given build

Tags: profile, provisioning

So the app builds fine for both iOS and Android.  Using transporter to get it to apple.

I'm lost on how to force native script to build it with the Distribution Provisioning Profile vs. the Development Profile.

Any help would be deeply and greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Brent.

I've tried the command line ns to get it to apple and login using cloud account with thirdpartypassword it sends the 6 digit code for verification.  Then errors on error 400. No other details other than that.

I moved to Transporter and here is the error it returns.

Asset validation failed (90161)
Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.vfgsports.amp [Payload/theorderapp.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal. (ID: 27d9f078-7d26-44e6-9c5c-272e6cc0e928)